# Trouble determining the range of years in a linked list

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

Hello guys i am having trouble implementing this particular problem. Every time i add a subscription to the list check if i need to update the "minYear" and "maxYear". Later use "minYear" and "maxYear" to check if the requested subscription period is valid. Basically I'm trying to determine the range of years of the linked list of subscriptions.

Class SubscriptionYear: First reads the year and cellular data of a particular country. This read from a file. It takes in the year and stats data for that year.

Below is my code for SubscriptionYear:

```
public class SubscriptionYear {

private int year;
private double subscriptions;
SubscriptionYear next;

//stores the year and it's statistical data.
public SubscriptionYear(int year,double subscriptions)
{
    setYear(year);
    setSubscription(subscriptions);
    this.next = null;
}
//sets the year
public void setYear(int Year)
{
    this.year= Year;
}
//sets the cellular data.
public void setSubscription(double value)
{
    this.subscriptions = value;
}
public int getYear()
{
    return year;
}   
 //returns the stat data
public double getSubscription()
{
    return subscriptions;
}
public String toString()
{
    return "Number of Subscriptions: "+subscriptions;
}
//sets the node
public void setNode(SubscriptionYear next)
{
    this.next = next;
}
public SubscriptionYear getNext()
{
    return this.next;
}
}
```

class Country:
This reads the Country Name and acts as a container for the Object node SubscripitpnYear that stores the year and stats data. It has variable field minYear and maxYear to check when a subscription is added to the list if it needs to be updated. use the minYear and maxYear to check if a subscription requested is valid. This is where i am having trouble implementing when i add a SusbcriptionYear to the list how do i check if i need to update minYear and maxYear? And use minYear and maxYear to check if a subscription is valid?

my class country:

```
public class Country  {

//variable fields.
private String countryNames;
private SubscriptionYear subscriptions;
private int minYear;
private int maxYear;

public Country(String country)
{
    this.countryNames = country;
    this.subscriptions = null;
    this.maxYear = 0;
    this.minYear = 9999;

}
//adds the subscription.
public void addSubscriptionYear(int year, double subscription)
{
    SubscriptionYear newNode = new SubscriptionYear(year, subscription);
    if(this.isEmpty())
    {
        newNode.setNode(subscriptions);
        subscriptions = newNode;
    }
    else{
        SubscriptionYear current = subscriptions;
        while(current.getNext()!=null)
        {
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        current.setNode(newNode);
    }
}

//need help implementing this function
public void update(int minYear, int maxYear)
{

}

//overrides the toString method and prints out the countries.
public String toString()
{
    String result="";
    result += "\n"+this.countryNames;
    SubscriptionYear current = subscriptions;
    while(current!=null)
    {
        result+="\t"+current.getSubscription();
        current = current.getNext();        
    }
    return result;
}
//returns countryName
 public String getName()
{
    return this.countryNames;
}
//overrides the equals method and returns country name if found
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    return this.countryNames.equalsIgnoreCase(((Country) obj).getName());
}
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return (subscriptions == null);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to take what you posted and distill it into something a bit more concentrated. Imagine you're writing an e-mail to your coworker. It is very hard for us to read paragraphs and paragraphs and figure out what you want. Give a couple of sentences of background, explain what you need to, then state your question explicitly. That way, it'll be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: Also LALA... When folks go to effort to answer your questions, you should select a "correct" answer.  Heck, one day you might troll posts trying to answer a few too.

Comment: @BrianT. Sorry about that I'm new to stack overflow. Will make sure to do that

Comment: @AlexK thanks for the suggestion as i have modified the question and more explicit. But how will this problem be solved. My initial idea or concept to tackle the problem was a similar approach to array out of bounds. But since we are dealing with list its quite different. Is my thinking on the right track

Comment: @BrianT. To address this problem my initial idea or concept to tackle the problem was a similar approach to array out of bounds. But since we are dealing with list its quite different. Is my thinking on the right track

Answer (score 0):

-1-
Humm, lots of code here but I'll try.

your `getNext()` method confused me, and probably many experienced Java developers.  In java collections (e.g. List), you can get an iterator (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).  There "hasNext()" is a boolean "is there another object?) and can be used in your `while()` control.  `next()` both returns the next item **and** advances the iterator to point to the following item.  Hence... having `getNext()` in both your `while()`, and in the following body looks suspect.

Your code uses `setNode()` to set "next", and `getNext()` to retrieve it.  Conventionally (and hence easier for many to understand intent) would be to follow naming conventions.  For member variable "node" this would be `setNode()` & `getNode()`.

-2-
OK, that said, it looks like this code:

```
    SubscriptionYear current = subscriptions;
    while(current.getNext()!=null)
    {
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    current.setNode(newNode);
```

walks the subscriptions and places `newNode` at the end.

Humm, I'm giving up confused.  You are using the same name "subscriptions" as two distinctly different things.  In `SubscriptionYear` it appears to be a count of how many subscriptions you have (why `double`?  `int` seems better).  However, in `Country` it is your home-made-list of `SubscriptionYear`, holding the 1st one.

IOM, the route to solution includes clarifying your code, using better names so you can understand what it does.

-3-
do you have a **specific** question beyond the comment in `update()` ?  Maybe you should indicate what that method is supposed to do, propose logic, etc.

--
Other observations:

-1-
`Country.equals()` is sketchy.  It should return `false`, not a `ClassCastException` if the passed in object is not of the same class.  Better:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    if (this==obj){return true;}
    if (! (obj instanceof Country)) { return false; }
    return this.countryNames.equalsIgnoreCase(((Country) obj).getName());
}
```

-2-
You have committed java-developer-sin; implementing ONE of `equals()` and `hashCode()`.  It is important to -always- implement both, or neither.  More on that here (read both equals() and hashCode() descriptions).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Comment: SusbcriptionYear takes 2 parameters. One is the year and 2nd is the statistical data for that year thats why i have an int and double. subscriptions is my first object in the list. I used the setter and getters to the set the node and get current node of subscriptionYear. I have never used iterators as i am new to java. My question was if was to add a Subscription to the list i need to update the minYear, and maxYear. And i use that to determine if a requested subscription is valid.

Comment: is there an example or could also show an example of how i will use the iterator within a class. I looked online right now and its a bit confusing. They have an inner class implementation. How would i use iterator if i was to implement in class Country.

Comment: IMO, your most significant issue is using confusing terms.  If your 2nd param has the meaning `statistical data`, why on earth call it `subscriptions`? ... code IS NOT intended to be write-once and never see again. [I would fail your current usage in a code review.] ... take some time and fix up your code, renaming things to make sense. ... as to "is there an example...". Perhaps your text book and class notes are a good place?